# Using the Laravel Eloquent Resource to errors

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent

I'm using the Laravel 5.5, and testing in my application the new [eloquent resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources), i'm able of return my data in json, however, if i have no data or something wrong occur, how i can return a error from this resource?

example returning my data:

```
public function show ($id)
{
   return new ProductResource(Product::find($id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `if` to check for integrity, and if it's not valid throw a custom exception

```
public function show($id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);

    if (! $product->isValidResource()) {
        throw new InvalidResourceException($product);
    }

    return new ProductResource($product);
}
```

Then you can create the exception file in `App\Exceptions` and, declaring the method `render` on it, you can customize the error to show

```
public function render()
{
    return response()->json([
        'result' => false,
        'message' => 'Invalid Resource: '.get_class($this->product) .' identified by '.$this->product->id
    ]);
}
```

Comment: this ```isValidResource()``` is a custom method?

Comment: Yes, is where you validate the resource checking for the attributes or whatever you want

Comment: should i extend some class to use the exception?

Comment: You only needs to extend `Exception`. Laravel detects if an Exception with the method `render` was thrown

Comment: not working to me. following everything you said. he just throw a lot of errors about the exception class i created.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that, `InvalidResourceException` currently exists in a Symfony Package, better to find another name 

Comment: actually i used another name haha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157502/discussion-between-leandro-and-lloople).